# Free Memory in CUDA after cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage without destroying the buffer

Tags: opengl, cuda

I am working on a project that uses a combination of OpenGL drawing techniques as well as CUDA to perform analysis.  I would like to use CUDA to generate a renderbuffer and then perform analysis on it with OpenGL.  Because of the number of buffers, I need for the memory to be free from CUDA after the renderbuffer is complete but for the buffer to be available for OpenGL still.

More specifically, I create the buffers with

```
glGenRenderbuffersEXT
glBindRenderbufferEXT
glRenderbuferStorageEXT
```

I then register them in CUDA with

```
cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage
```

, which uses memory from CUDA.  However, when I go to unregister the renderbuffers with

```
cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource
```

the memory is not freed.  I do not want to destroy the buffer with

```
glDeleteBuffers
```

because I still need them for computation but also need to use CUDA to work on other buffers.  Is there some other CUDA call I can perform to free this memory without destroying the buffer?

Answer (score 1):

You say, cudaGraphicsRegisterImage "uses memory from CUDA," but have you measured how much? Registering the buffer with CUDA does just that - it just notifies the OpenGL driver that CUDA also wants to see the buffer.  The memory cost should be very modest.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the reverse. Create the frame buffer in cuda and register them in OpenGL.

The memory between opengl and CUDA is the same, changes only the owner (cuda driver or opengl driver).

Another ,slow, solution would be to download the memory into RAM and do the processing step by step
switching between cuda and opengl.

Third solution is to buy a card with more memory.

Comment: The first solution sounds great, but I am not sure how to do it.  Could you point me to some of the functions that I would use to both create the frame buffer in CUDA and then register it in OpenGL?