# cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage gives cudaErrorMemoryAllocation

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda

### The Scenario

I'm creating two quite large, equally sized OpenGL 3D textures. The first one is a single-channel 16bit texture, the second one has four channels and 8 bits per texel. Than I need to register the two of them with CUDA.

The application I'm working on is 32bit. System characteristics: Win 7 64bit, NVIDIA GeForce 540M 2GB

### The Problem

When using 512x512x391 or larger textures, my call to `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage` gives me a `cudaErrorMemoryAllocation`, although this return value is not even part of the list of possible return values, specified by the documentation of `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage`. One can find this list [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_Toolkit_Reference_Manual.pdf) on page 94. There are no memory-expansive operations performed before. However, it *does* work with smaller textures, such as 512x512x71.

Querying the free device memory right before the `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage` invocation tells about 1778 MB to be free.

### Deliberations

1. One explanation might be that the return value is the error code of some previous invocation. I can basically eliminate this possibility by putting a `cudaGetLastError` right before the `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage` invocation and checking it's return value: it gives me a `cudaSuccess`.
2. I've performed some calculations. The memory required by the two 3D textures is:

   (512 * 512 * 391) texels * (4 channels * 1 bytes per texel + 1 channel * 2 bytes per texel) = 586.5 MB

   This is not *that* much, especially as my graphics device has 2 GB of dedicated memory.
3. I've also checked the total memory acquired by the process, just to make sure that this is none of this Win32-2GB-limitation issues: according to the task manager, the total process' memory size is about 279 MB, right before the `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage` invocation.
4. According to [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6143736/1444073), the memory costs of the `cudaGraphicsRegisterImage` operation should be very low.

### Some Code

Acquisition of the two 3D textures:

```
glTexImage3D( GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_INTENSITY16
            , size.x, size.y, size.z
            , 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, bufferPtr );

glTexImage3D( GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA8
            , size.x, size.y, size.z
            , 0, GL_RGB, GL_BYTE, nullptr );
```

I've let off the texture generation and -binding for better overview.

Texture registration with CUDA:

```
size_t free, total;
CHECK_CUDA( cudaMemGetInfo( &free, &total ) );
qDebug() << "Free Memory:" << free / ( 1024 * 1024 ) << "MB";

enum resourceIndices{ FIRST_RESOURCE = 0, SECOND_RESOURCE = 1 };
cudaGraphicsResource* resources[ 2 ];

CHECK_CUDA( cudaGetLastError() );
CHECK_CUDA( cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage( &resources[ FIRST_RESOURCE ]
                                       , firstTextureID
                                       , GL_TEXTURE_3D
                                       , cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsReadOnly ) );

CHECK_CUDA( cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage( &resources[ SECOND_RESOURCE ]
                                       , secondTextureID
                                       , GL_TEXTURE_3D
                                       , cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsSurfaceLoadStore ) );
```

The macro `CHECK_CUDA` simply checks the return value and throws exceptions. It fails on the first `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage` invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippets looks fine to me. However you said you're on a 32 bit system. And that could be the problem: Your process got only 2GiB of address space. And depending on how this address space was allocated, it may very well be, that there's no **contiguous** slice large enough left. So even if there's still plenty of memory, you simply may have run out of available address space. And since every piece of CUDA memory is mapped into process address space, even device memory, this may be very likely to happen.

It's a well known problem on 32 bit systems, known as *address space fragmentation*. This is actually the real benefit of 64 bit systems: Not so much the amount of memory addressable, but the sheer size of address space that simplifies memory management so much, because it is so hard to fill it up, that address space fragmentation is not a practical issue.

My suggestion: Test your program on a 64 bit system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But wouldn't the task manager tell me that the process is at least *near* the 2GiB limit? As I've already written, is says that the process only occupies about 200 MB. Since there haven't been any memory-expensive operations before, it's hard to believe, that 1,8 GiB are so heavily fragmented.

Comment: @theV0ID: No it wouldn't because address space fragmentation doesn't consume memory. There's still much plenty address space around. The problem is, that there's no single large chunk of space left into the allocated amount would fit. Think it about this way: You got plenty of little 2×2 Lego block, but what you need is one single large 16×2 block, and there's no such one left in your box of Lego bricks.

Comment: Hmm, thinking about this, this metaphor makes an excellent base for a tutorial video on address space fragmentation. Now where's my video camera..? ;)

Comment: But why does CUDA map 'every piece of device memory' into my process address space? That doesn't make sense to me. If this would be true, than what is the purpose of the fourth `cudaMemcpy` argument? It basically specifies, which address space the given pointers belong to. If you were right, this argument would be redundant. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @theV0ID: To make sure, that the address space is not going to be used by other allocators. Remember that you can do pointer arithmetic on device pointers just as fine to address only portions in the device memory not at the 0 offset. If CUDA did not allocate a such large region of the address space (it allocated address space, not memory!)  some other part of the system may try to use that portion of address space for allocation, colliding with CUDAs needs.

Comment: @theV0ID: As why there are those copy direction parameters to cudaMemcpy I have no idea, as this was perfectly deducible from the addresses involved. You've to ask NVidia why they did design the CUDA API that way.

Comment: Once upon a time it was not deducible.  Then UVA came along.   Now with UVA enabled, it is deducible, and so a new copy direction parameter (choice) was added "cudaMemcpyDefault" which says "deduce the direction from the pointers I have supplied."  Or you can still use the old parameters, HostToDevice and DeviceToHost

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Tahnks for the reminder, I wasn't thinking about that. TBH it's been an very long time, since I've worked with a system that had multiple periphials sharing address space. Even 15 year old DSPs (traditionally Harvard architectured) place text and data segment in different segments of a unified address space. As for the OP: Just switch to a 64 bit OS already. You're using a CUDA capable device, your host machine is 64 bit capable for sure then.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on `cudaMemcpy`! For the topic @datenwolf, you wrote I should switch to a 64bit OS. You actually meant that I should compile my application for 64bit, right? My OS already is 64bit.

Comment: @theV0ID: If you already have a 64 bit OS running, then yes: *Do* compile as 64 bits executable. It gives you more address space, than you can fragment in any reasonable running time of a process: Say you fragment 2GiB of address space into unusable small block within 1s. In the worst case then a 64 bit address space would take way over 100 years to fragment, but it's more likely to happen on a logarithmic scales, so I'd say several 1000 years :)

Comment: Unfortunately building my application for 64bit is not an option, since it depends on many 32bit libraries.

**But:** [According to NVIDIA](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/cuda_webinars_GPUDirect_uva.pdf) the application is required to be 64bit for UVA. Since my application is 32bit, I would assume that UVA is **disabled**.

Comment: @theV0ID: Well, just try it out. Other than address space fragmentation I can think of no other reason for this to happen (except if large amounts of GPU RAM are consumed, but you do the check with cudaMemGetInfo, so… – Also is there are significant reason why you want your program to be 32 bits? It will not gain you any computing performance. Biggest concern is the increase in memory (bandwidth) consumed by pointers, but really, that's microoptimization.

Comment: The reason I need my application to be 32bit is that it depends on dozens of 32bit libraries, that do not exist in 64bit version, such as Qt. And as far as I can tell there is no way to link 32bit libraries to a 64bit application or vice versa.

Comment: @theV0ID: Qt not being available as 64 bits? That's news to me. Let me check my system… Uh, I have 64 bit builds of Qt here, just fine. I'm pretty sure there are 64 bit versions of all the libraries you need. If the library in question is open source, then there's a 64 bit version for sure. If not pre built, then nothing prevents you from building it for 64 bits yourself.